# Handling Exception when bulkwrite with ordered as false in MongoDB java

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

I am using the Mongo DB java driver:

```
collection.bulkWrite(documents);
```

I have 1 million records to be inserted. If the insertion of one of the records fails then on the first failure the remaining records won't get inserted.
In order to avoid this I found that there are `BulkWriteOptions` with `ordered` as `false`;

```
collection.bulkWrite(documents, new BulkWriteOptions().ordered(false) )
```

If any exception occurs during the above operation, can we get the list of the records for which `bulkwrite` failed and can we try inserting those records again?

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for something similar..

```
BulkWriteOptions bulkWriteOptions = new BulkWriteOptions();
bulkWriteOptions.ordered(true);

BulkWriteResult bulkWriteResult = null;
try {
    bulkWriteResult = mongoCollection.bulkWrite(updateDocuments,
            bulkWriteOptions);
} catch (BulkWriteException e) {
    List<BulkWriteError> bulkWriteErrors = e.getWriteErrors();
    for (BulkWriteError bulkWriteError : bulkWriteErrors) {
        int failedIndex = bulkWriteError.getIndex();
        Long failedEntity = entityList.get(failedIndex);
        System.out.println("Failed record: " + failedEntity);
        //handle rollback
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All bulkWrite operations that fail are reported in arrays in the return document, along with the full document that failed to insert. For example, this code via the java driver:

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("bulk");

List<WriteModel<Document>> writes = new ArrayList<WriteModel<Document>>();
 writes.add(new InsertOneModel<Document>(new Document("_id", 1)));
 writes.add(new InsertOneModel<Document>(new Document("_id", 2)));
 writes.add(new InsertOneModel<Document>(new Document("_id", 2)));
 writes.add(new InsertOneModel<Document>(new Document("_id", 4)));
BulkWriteResult bulkWriteResult = collection.bulkWrite(writes);

System.out.println(bulkWriteResult.toString());
```

returns this:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoBulkWriteException: 
  Bulk write operation error on server localhost:27017. Write errors:
  [BulkWriteError{index=2, code=11000, message='E11000 duplicate key 
  error collection: test.bulk index: _id_ dup key: { : 2 }',
  details={ }}].
```

You didn’t mention what release of MongoDB you are using, but here is the version 3.2 manual entry for unordered bulkWrites: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/ if you want to look into that further.

However, if by “exception” you meant in the middle of the load operation the client or mongod processes crashed, or there was a hardware or network incident, then there won’t be a clean exit from bulkWrite and thus no bulkWriteResult output as above.  Unordered bulkWrites execute operations in parallel and not necessarily in the order entered, and it is even more complicated with sharded collections and distributed clusters, so it is impossible to know exactly which operations completed before the crash.  The only solution is to repeat the whole job, which usually requires you to remove all documents that inserted successfully the first time.

If you were loading to a new or empty collection you can simply drop and recreate it.  If there is a unique key with an index you can just repeat the load as the documents that inserted OK the first time will be rejected as duplicates.  Otherwise you will have to run a cleanup job to remove all the documents that could/should have been inserted before starting the reload attempt, which if they aren’t easily identified can be problematic.

The best approach for this scenario is to break large load operations into smaller pieces, so you have four load jobs each with one quarter of the data (or twenty each with 5%, and so on).  There is more effort to design the load process this way, but it is much faster to repeat one job with 5% of the total data than have to repeat a single load that failed at the 95% mark.

If you add a loadNum field with a different value for each of the jobs, then count(“loadNum”:n) can be used to confirm that all the documents loaded, and remove(“loadNum”:n) will remove all documents from a job that was only partially successful.